# Visual Studio 2017 Installer TypeInitializationException

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

After having a problem with my installation of Visual Studio 2017 Microsoft recommended me to run `InstallCleanup.exe -full` this command removed Visual Studio 2017 and the Visual Studio installer from my computer but in the process broke something.

Now when I try to install Visual Studio 2017 the Visual Studio 2017 installer throws a TypeInitializationException whenever I select a version of Visual Studio to install.

[image: Exception]

The log file shows the following stack trace:

```
2017-05-25T17:19:18 : Verbose : Getting product. [installerId: SetupEngine, productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community].
2017-05-25T17:19:21 : Error : Failed to get product. [installerId: SetupEngine, productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community, error: TypeInitializationException at The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility' threw an exception.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility.ReplaceSpecialFolders(String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility.ReplaceVariables(String value, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ProductInstaller.GetSerializableProduct()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ProductsProviderService.GetProduct(String channelId, String productId)]
```

Unfortunately I've been unable to correct this. I've redownload the installer. uninstalled and removed anything related to VS2017, rebooted, cleaned the temp folder. Nothing seems to have any affect.

I've asked Microsoft for guidance [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61522/the-visual-studio-installer-update-failed-signatur-1.html?childToView=61562#comment-61562), but two similar bug reports [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41735/typeinitializationexception-when-launcher-the-2017.html) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25737/cant-install-vs2017-cause-typeinitializationexcept.html) stay unanswered, so I've got little hope.

I would look at the source code for the `StringUtility` class that seems to cause the problem. But I do not believe that is open source. (I could not find a similar class on referencesource). I would also try to debug the running application by attaching a debugger, but alas I have no Visual Studio and can't install a new one :).

Does anybody have any clue how I could try to figure out what causes this Exception? Or what dependencies I could check?

Edit: after using Collect.exe to gather more information I've found the InnerException:

```
05/25/2017 17:55:17 : Error : System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Absolute path information is required.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.Environment.InternalGetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder, SpecialFolderOption option, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility.ReplaceSpecialFolders(String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Utility.StringUtility.ReplaceVariables(String value, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ProductInstaller.GetSerializableProduct()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.ProductsProviderService.GetProduct(String channelId, String productId)Failed to get a catalog
```

Looks like there is some sheneningans with an invalid path? But how will I ever find out what path :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another day of searching I figured it out.

Notice how the stack trace includes this line

```
at System.Environment.InternalGetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder, SpecialFolderOption option, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
```

So the invalid folder is one of Windows Special Folders. Of which there are only a few. With a Powershell script I tested all Special folders. I then noticed that the following powershell command threw a very similar exception.

```
 [environment]::GetFolderPath("MyVideos")
```

Digging further I found the following registry key:
[image]

Note the missing `\` it should be `D:\Videos\` not `D:Videos` I manually edited this a while ago. The path seems to be valid in some Windows functions. But not in the .Net function.

I deleted the Library and then restored the defaults. (Right click, the library in the library pane to delete it. Then right click on the library icon and choose restore defaults.)

After *rebooting* (without it it wouldn't work) The PS script showed that the Special Folder path worked. And voila! the Visual Studio Installer also worked again :D.